# numpy.dtype error in machine learning code (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, version-control, machine-learning

I am just trying to run a scikit-learn example source code successfully, but am getting an consistent error. The code can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_outlier_detection.html) - it has around 90 lines of code, so it wouldn't be efficient to put it in here. However, whenever I run it, I get the error message called from the **Import sklearn** stating:

```
File "plot_outlier_detection.py", line 33, in <module>
  from sklearn import svm
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
  from .base import clone
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
  from .utils.fixes import signature
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

The main error is

```
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

and I've looked into many Stackoverflow posts already, saying that I need to update my numpy, matplotlib, scipy, which I've done already multiple times (upgrade / uninstall+install using pip / uninstall+install from source), but the same error still shows up (I also reinstalled sklearn). I think I know why this is the case:

When I use python in terminal and check the numpy version I get

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
'1.9.2'
```

However, when I try installing or upgrading through pip -- I get the message

```
numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
```

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390895/why-isnt-pip-updating-my-numpy-and-scipy) Stackoverflow query about this, and they said to use easy_install as python doesn't read from the right path in Macs (IDK, can someone confirm?) so I did it through easy_install, and get this message

```
Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy 1.11.0
Processing numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
numpy 1.11.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing f2py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for numpy
Finished processing dependencies for numpy
```

which is the exact same thing. I don't really know what's going on. Can anyone help me?

For reference of versions:

```
Python - 2.7.10
Numpy - 1.9.2
Matplotlib - 1.4.3
Scipy - 0.13.0b1
```

*The rest of the versions are also not up to date..but they derive from numpy's version being up-to-date.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Anaconda (2.5.0) on my Ubuntu (14.04)
With Anaconda 2.5.0 my versions are:

python 2.7.11

Numpy 1.10.4

Scipy 0.17.0

I've download the code from the link, and it worked perfectly on my machine

Can you try to install Anaconda and see if it solve your problems?
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: it works in Anaconda, but I would rather use a non-application to write my code (ie through terminal/vim). I will use this as a temporary solution for now, but I would still like to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by " I would rather use a non-application to write my code (ie through terminal/vim)"?

Comment: Anaconda saves the complexity of installing the most-up-to-date versions of numpy,pandas,scipy, etc.... e.g. in pandas official web site, they recommended installing it using anaconda: "http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html - The easiest way for the majority of users to install pandas is to install it as part of the Anaconda distribution", similar recommendation in the case of scipy - https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: Note that you can write your python script through terminal/vim even if you install the packages using anacoda.

Comment: Did I answer your questions? If so - please accept it.