# matplotlib pyplot.colormaps 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colormap

Python 3.9.7
anaconda command line client 1.9.0

I copy + paste code from [this tutorial from matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multivariate_marker_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multivariate-marker-plot-py).

The error is at line 24.

```py
cmap = plt.colormaps["plasma"]
```

> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

So perhaps matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps used to be a dictionary but now it is not.
The [documentation on matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps) also suggests similar form as in the tutorial.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
cmap = mpl.colormaps['viridis']
```

There are a number of questions here, answers to which would be helpful.

• How to report to maintainiers of the matplotlib site?

• What is the most up to date way to obtain a colormap from matplotlib.pyplot.colorplots?

Thanks all

Comment: Make sure you are using the version of the docs that goes with the version of Matplotlib you have installed.  There were changes to accessing colormaps in recent Matplotlib, and you do not sate what version of Matplotlib you have installed.

Comment: If you don't have the latest matplotlib version, you can try `cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

JohanC answered in the comments. Older versions of Matplotlib ( including version 3.4.3 which I am on ) use:

```py
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
```

I should indeed have [gotten my matplotlib version information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473600/matplotlib-version) and either upgraded or looked at the matplotlib homepage [https://matplotlib.org/stable/] more closely. Toward the top right, there is a drop down menu with the word "stable" on it (similar to the [path](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/parts-url#:%7E:text=A%20URL%20consists%20of%20ten,at%20least%20three%20of%20them.) of the url, stable ). I can select 3.4 from the dropdown menu to get to https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/index.html. From there I eventually find the [matplotlib.cm.get_cmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap) page.